# Sorting potentially already sorted sequence -- stl::sort efficiecny

Tags: c++, stl

I need to sort a stl::vector of which I know there is a significant chance that it is already sorted.

I wonder if I should do something like this:

```
void my_sort(vector& v){
    if( is_not_sorted(v) ) std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());
}
```

Or if this is already done for me within std::sort (which would mean worse performance on vectors that are very unlikely to be already sorted).

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Testing whether an array is sorted and actually sorting it is the same thing, I would have thought?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Umm, you can test whether an array is sorted in O(n), but you can only sort it (using element comparison) in O(n log n).

Comment: @JonathanPotter: for bubble sort, yes! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The C++ Standard doesn't ask `std::sort` implementations to check for already-sorted input, so by all means add that and benchmark to see if it's useful in your case.  What works best likely depends on data sizes, number of elements, CPU cache sizes and relative speeds, performance of your `<` comparison, probability of it being presorted etc..

As it would be sub-optimal to check if an input was pre-sorted in cases where it never or very rarely happens, you being able to trivially compose it *when useful* from `std::sort` and [`std::is_sorted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) is actually preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best when it comes to complexity but sorting is O(nlogn) whereas testing is O(n) because you iterate through the vector once testing each time the current element with the previous.

I'd say its not worth the test unless you have a VERY large vector and you do something like having a sorted_flag=true and once you find the first element out of order you then resort to sorting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really asking about the [STL](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/), you can just look into its implementation and see what sorting algorithm it uses. Some sorting algorithms can take advantage of an already-sorted sequence (bubblesort), some can't (quicksort, depends on pivot selection).

However, I suspect you're actually asking about the C++ standard library and not STL. In such case, it depends on your standard library's implementation. The standard itself does not mandate any specific behaviour in case the sequence is already sorted. I believe most common standard library implementations of `std::sort` are based on introsort. Since that's based on quicksort, I would assume its ability to take advantage of "already sorted" depends on pivot selection—again an implementation detail of the standard library.

So there's no clear-cut answer. You should definitely measure, both with the prior check and without it, and decice based on those measurements.